# UDK Kismet fractured mesh

Tags: unreal-development-kit, kismet-udk

I know how to make a fractured mesh and have one for a ceiling. How do I set up the Kismet so that when the player touches a trigger the mesh explodes and falls to the floor?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

First create your fractured mesh and add it to the scene then create a trigger volume

Next under physics actor classes drag and drop a radial impulse actor into the scene and and size it around the fractured mesh then go into its properties and set it to fracture

Open Kismet and inside Kismet have your trigger volume selected and place it down as a touch

then create a toggle hook the trigger to the on part of the toggle

Select the impulse actor and add it into kismet set the target of the toggle to the impulse actor

To ensure it does not start already on or off as well you can set the impulse actor to off upon level loaded ... Hope that helped!

http://forums.epicgames.com/archive/index.php/t-750148.html